# How to work with my Apex Classes and my Lightning component on my local environment?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, sublime

I'm working on a project that has Apex Classes and Lightning Components. I've been trying to find a way to work with both on my local environment using a IDE, preferably Sublime Text 3.

I've tried Ant, MavensMate and force CLI migration tool but haven't successfully synced with salesforce for both Apex and Lightning components on one IDE.

Does anyone has any tips on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave Carrol has a cool package for sublime called "sublime lightning" you can check it out here: https://github.com/dcarroll/sublime-lightning . I'm pretty sure you can sync Apex classes as well.

Comment: I have been down this rode. Correct me if I am wrong, but there is no support for Apex as far as I understand.

Comment: I forgot to get back to you. I got it working after a little while with this package. There were some bumps on the way, but I got it figure out. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84914/error-no-package-xml-found-when-i-try-to-save-static-resources-and-or-apex-c

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to alternatives to Sublime, [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com) has limited support for Lightning components development right now with full support coming in the next few months.  You can currently deploy and retrieve Aura bundle metadata including support for deploy-on-save behavior of the entire bundle when editing constituent files, and you can use IntelliJ IDEA's native XML, JavaScript, and CSS editors to edit the various content types.  This is in addition to the tool's full support for Apex and Visualforce, static resource bundles, and other metadata types.

Over the next few months I'll be adding full support for completion, reference navigation, integrated API docs, etc., for Lightning similar to what is currently offered for Apex and Visualforce development, but there are already quite a few users using the tool for Lightning development today.

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on Sublime then one option is:
[force cli](https://force-cli.herokuapp.com/) + [sublime-lightning](https://github.com/dcarroll/sublime-lightning)
sublime-lightning page has a detailed instruction of how to set it up.

Comment: I have been down this rode. Correct me if I am wrong, but there is no support for Apex as far as I understand.

Comment: You mentioned MavensMate so I assumed you are already using it for Apex  and only needed to add Aura/Lightning support. The whole package (for Sublime Text) would be: MavensMate + sublime-lightning. Note - I am not a Sublime user, so this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

@Vinicius Santana, you can try [HaoIDE](https://github.com/xjsender/haoide) for Sublime Text 3, I have built basic functions for Lightning development and am still working on building comprehensive features for it.